# WMI LastBootUpTime is not updated when server reboots

Tags: powershell, wmi

I am getting the LastBootUpTime of some servers using PowerShell's cmdlet Get-WmiObject.

`[Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime((Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName $server).LastBootUpTime)`

I have noticed that some servers (windows Server 2003, 2008 R2 and 2012 R2) return the LastBootUpTime with a date in the year 2014 (250+ days ago), while that I know for sure that the servers have been rebooted a couple of days ago within the Windows update cycle.

Running the following command on the servers that are affected shows me the correct last boot up time.

`net statistics server`

It seems that the WMI property LastBootUpTime is not updated "anymore" when the server restarts

What is the cause of this flaw and is there a way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unlikely that the attribute is not updated, there might be a name resolution conflict for example, and one server does have uptime over 250 days, and those servers you test are unreachable by RPC. Check if `gwmi` does not throw an unreachable exception, that can potentially not overwrite the data in where do you assign the result of this command.

Comment: Executing the PowerShell command on the server (specifying the -ComputerName or not) gives me the same result in the year 2014 (2014-11-02 22:39:50.000). The server did restart with the Windows update cycle a couple of days ago. The command `net statistics server` returns me the correct boot up time (7/9/2015 10:07:56 AM), bginfo from sysinternals is also showing the correct boot time (7/9/2015 10:07 AM). So it looks to me that the WMI property is not updated correctly.

Comment: I have 14 servers of about 300 that are not showing the correct boot up time. I have checked them manually by entering the server using RDP and execute the commands mentioned in the question (removing the -ComputerName parameter).

Comment: You could use the eventlog and filter by the eventid that correponds to the start of the eventlog service, 6005 .

Comment: @Kiran, your proposal can work as a workaround but it does not answer or solves the issue I am facing with the WMI property that is not being updated correctly.

Comment: Are these virtual machines that are all guests of the same host?  Is the host's time accurate?  Do you get the same results from WMI when the commands are run locally?

Comment: Yes, all are virtual machines, but they are not running on the same host (ESX server), I get the same result from WMI when running the commands locally. Although when running the command `net statistics server` the startup time is correct.

Comment: This is still a problem. I booted the system this morning, 2022-06-16. `(Get-CimInstance Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime.tostring('yyyy-MM-dd')` is returning `2022-06-02`.